# Get return value of dwr function within the located function

Tags: javascript, dwr

I want get the return value of dwr method within the located function.Ie, I have a javascript function name checkvalue().Within that I have a DWR call.I want the value returned by the DWR method.I have set the value to a hidden variable.But it cannot get properly.How can I do that?Please help me.

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function checkvalue(applNo){
     classDAO.getstatusofApplication(applNo,getstatusofApp); 
     var status=document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value;
   }

   function getstatusofApp(status){  
     document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value=status;   
    }
</script>
```

In the above example I set the dwr return value 'status' to a hidden field and call the hidden field within the checkvalue method.But it shows null.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey:Ya.That I know.Here I am using a DWR call.ie,Java method

Comment: It is worth checking the tags SO adds to make sure they are right.

Comment: Here I am using a DWR call.ie,Java method

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code the line

```
var status=document.getElementById("hiddenfield").value;
```

gets executed before the function `getstatusofApp` is being called. try logging in console the steps the code is executed.

So what you really should do is-

```
function checkvalue(applNo){
   classDAO.getstatusofApplication(applNo, function(status){
      getstatusofApp(status);
      alert(status);
      // here you have the status value you need not have 
      // to read it from hidden variable
   }); 
}
```